# Android scrollable layout with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am making a layout with two recyclerview seperated with a text view in the middle. Now I want the whole layout to be scrollable, what I have now is a textview stuck in the middle and the layout not scrollable, I tried wrapping them with scrollview but didn't work , still the same behaviour.
How do you get the whole layout to be scrollable?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/today_booking_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e8d6b6"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/today_booking_recycler_view"
        android:id="@+id/tvRelativeLayout"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="seperator"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_booking_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvRelativeLayout"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can't keep RecyclerView inside RecyclerView.

Comment: I think you need to use `NestedScrollView`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for Scrolling whole layout :-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

 // your layout which has to be scrolled

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```